# GL_ALPHA8 was removed from OpenGL 3.1, what are the alternatives?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

From what I've seen, the `GL_ALPHA8` internal pixel format has been removed from the OpenGL core specification in OpenGL 3.1. It seems that there are no more pixel formats with an alpha channel but no RGB channels. Does that mean that the only alternative is to create an `GL_RGBA8` texture and set the RGB components to 255, therefore wasting 75% of its memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the `GL_R8` format. If changing your textures to swizzle properly is a concern, you can set up a [swizzle mask](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask) to do it at fetch time. For instance:

```
GLenum swizzleMask = {GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_RED};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Comment: Ah! Excellent, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Being a GL 4.2 core addition, I guess this is not something that risks getting deprecated in the near future?

Comment: @Trillian: It was added in 3.3, not 4.2. And nothing has been removed from OpenGL since 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GL_RED` and treat it as alpha in the fragment shader (e.g. `output_colour = vec4(1., 1., 1., texture2D(sampler, texcoords).r);`).

Comment: Yes, but then I have to use a special shader when using alpha textures, which I'd rather avoid. A way to tell OpenGL to pre-swizzle the components so I can read the R components as A would be ideal, if such a thing exists.

Comment: @Trillian: It's either special format and special shader, or generic format and generic shader. Pick your poison.